# Sorting a stats file in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, readfile

So here's the file I need to sort.

```
Jump067
1
4c3jump1
JUMPMOD067TOP10TIMES
 10/07/13 17.363001 259 04/10/12 17.385000 343 04/10/12 17.678001 235 05/12/12 17.685001 265 10/07/13 17.980001 210 21/10/14 18.478001 773 06/06/12 18.523001 208 10/07/13 18.592001 214 27/06/14 18.772001 349 21/10/14 18.978001 630 21/10/14 19.025002 772 10/07/13 19.240002 69 02/05/12 19.356001 219 27/06/14 19.604000 693 24/04/12 19.756001 204
JUMPMOD067ALLTIMES
 24/04/12 19.756001 204 6 02/05/12 19.356001 219 1 06/06/12 18.523001 208 1 05/12/12 17.685001 265 6 10/07/13 17.363001 259 8 05/12/12 23.172001 353 7 04/10/12 17.678001 235 2 04/10/12 17.385000 343 1 27/06/14 18.772001 349 6 05/12/12 24.316002 299 2 04/04/13 22.014002 61 2 10/07/13 17.980001 210 2 10/07/13 19.240002 69 6 10/07/13 18.592001 214 7 26/08/13 22.243002 549 4 26/08/13 22.927002 580 4 19/09/13 20.098001 579 3 26/10/13 104.303001 603 1 29/12/13 52.244003 290 1 06/03/14 28.275002 294 1 02/04/14 22.736002 406 3 27/06/14 19.604000 693 3 11/09/14 20.366001 540 2 21/10/14 18.478001 773 8 21/10/14 20.771002 714 4 21/10/14 19.025002 772 4 21/10/14 18.978001 630 2 21/10/14 21.544001 510 1
```

The file is for stats for a quake mod. The format is as follows:

[version of game] [1(always will be 1)] [mapname] [JUMPMOD067TOP10TIMES]

The top10 times section is in the format [date] [finish_time] [user id]

[JUMPMOD067ALLTIMES]

The alltimes section is in the format [date] [finish_time] [user id] [map_completions]

What I need to do is read in the text file sort the alltimes section in order of [finish_time], remove the [map_completions] number, then replace the top10times section with the sorted version of all times. This has to be done for roughly 2500 files, or I would do it by hand. Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you write any code to do this? If so, can you post that as well?

Comment: I am just starting the process, and want to be sure I get off to the right start. It 100% needs to be in ruby, and I haven't touched ruby in quite a few years.

Comment: So by the looks of that, there are no newlines for each row?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on the expected output?  You're going to replace the top10times section with the sorted alltimes, but are you going to keep the alltimes?  Do you still want no newlines between data records?  Do you still want to keep the "heading" JUMPMOD067TOP10TIMES even if it contains the sorted list of alltimes, which might have more than 10 things?

If you can concretely show the expected output for this example, it'll probably clarify a lot of the requirements.

Comment: Why are you copying an answer to your question? If you wish to thank Erik, select his answer. You could also leave a thank you comment on his answer, but that's somewhat superfluous. Questions should remain questions. When you have time, read this [SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, where you pass in the scores filename as a command line argument and it writes to `filename.calculated`.

On *nix, you could invoke it across all of the scores files with `find . -name '*scores' -exec ruby calculate_high_scores.rb {} \;`

```
file_name = ARGV[0]
file_content = File.read(file_name)
file_content.match /([\w\d]+TOP10TIMES).* ([\w\d]+ALLTIMES)/

top_10_label = $1.upcase
all_times_label = $2.upcase

header, scores = file_content.split(top_10_label)
top_10, all_times = file_content.split(all_times_label)

sorted = all_times.split(' ').each_slice(4).to_a.sort do |a,b|
  b[1].to_f <=> a[1].to_f
end

calculate_top_10 = sorted[0..9].map { |score| score[0..2].join(' ') }.join(' ')

result = "#{header}#{top_10_label} #{calculate_top_10} #{all_times_label}#{all_times}"

File.open("#{file_name}.calculated", "w") do |f|
  f << result
end
```

Good luck!